# How to select the same div after refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

If I have 5 divs like so :

```
<div id="container">
   <div class="selected"></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

The div that is selected can be changed by clicking another. Now if I refresh the content of the container using ajax call I would like to keep the div selected. How do I acheive this?

I know I can get the selected div by using :

```
var selectedDiv = $('.selected');
```

But how do I use this to select it again?

Comment: So you want to keep you want to keep the selected on the n-th div after the ajax replace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before you do the Ajax call, get the index of the selected `div` and store it in a variable:

```
var selected_index = $('#container div.selected').index();
```

Then, after you updated the content, use the index to selected the correct div:

```
$('#container div').eq(selected_index).addClass('selected');
```

Answer (score 0):

edit : as it seems there is the same answer posted just seconds before i do lol

var selected

```
 $('div').click(function(){
    selected = $("#selected").index()+1;
    })
```

then select the element

```
var element = '.div-class:nth-child('+selected+')';
$(element)
```

---

do this when the user select a div

var selected

```
$('div').click(function(){
selected = $("#selected").index();
})
```

and then select the element again using `.eq(selected)`

Answer (score 0):

Update your variable to store the div's index.

```
var selectedDiv = $('#container div').index($('.selected'));
```

Then in the success function of your ajax call set the class to the previously selected div.

```
success: function(){
  $('#container div:eq(selectedDiv)').addClass('selected');
}
```

Comment: `eq` does not return the index.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. Updated with .index()